# Good practice to manually type check and test for function arguments?

Tags: javascript

I'm applying TDD while creating my project, and I'm implementing a lot of tests and checks for my functions to ensure their arguments are correctly input.

I have no issue with this, but my code is starting to look congested with all the argument checks. Is this proper practice or is argument checking not generally implemented like this?

```js
export default class Ship {
  constructor(shipLength) {
    if (typeof shipLength !== 'number') throw new Error('Length must be a number');
    if (arguments.length !== 1) throw new Error('Must enter only 1 argument');
    if (shipLength < 1) throw new Error('Length must be greater than 0');
    if (shipLength % 1) throw new Error('Length must be an integer');
    
    this.length = shipLength;
    this.hits = Array(this.length).fill(false);
  }

  hit(location) {
    if (typeof location !== 'number') throw new Error('Must be a number');
    if (arguments.length !== 1) throw new Error('Can only accept one argument')
    if (location > this.length - 1) throw new Error('Must be within ship body');
    if (location < 0) throw new Error('Cant be negative');
    if (location % 1) throw new Error('Must be an integer');
  
    this.hits[location] = true;
  }
}
```

```js
import Ship from "../src/ship";

describe('Test that the constructor', () => {
  it('accepts only one parameter of type number', () => {
    expect(() => new Ship(3)).not.toThrow();
    expect(() => new Ship(1,2,3)).toThrow();
    expect(() => new Ship([1,2,3])).toThrow();
    expect(() => new Ship('asd')).toThrow();
  });
  it('doesnt take < 1 as length', () => {
    expect(() => new Ship(0)).toThrow();
    expect(() => new Ship(-1)).toThrow();
  });
  it('only accepts integers', () => {
    expect(() => new Ship(1.1)).toThrow();
  });
  it('sets the passed ship length', () => {
    expect(new Ship(3).length).toBe(3);
  });
  it('creates a hit array', () => {
    expect(new Ship(3).hits).toEqual([false, false, false]);
  })
});
```

Comment: Why not use a library for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do runtime validation of *user supplied values*. Because those only appear at runtime and errors in them must be handled at runtime. Doing this for values which are passed internally in your code is usually overkill. Because while those errors will surface at runtime, you cannot do anything about them at runtime; you need to fix them by fixing your code. So runtime checks for those values might help you discover bugs in your code, but at the cost of very convoluted code; and it's not even guaranteed to easily help you discover those bugs, if your code doesn't happen to take that particular path.

What *does* help unearth these types of bugs at development time is a static type checker like [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org). Using it often makes more sense than these runtime type checks.

Comment: This makes sense and is good to hear. So if my project was a js library, then the public API methods would have such tests right? Also aside from type checking, are other checks like the range of the input and number of arguments (too little, in particular) not checked by internal code? So there's always an inherent assumption that internal functions are communicating properly?

Comment: You can enforce that internal methods are communicating properly with static type checks, yes. If you do that rigorously, that gets you there 90% of the way. There are some checks which may not be expressible as static type checks. For those you can do runtime testing, if the correctness of the following code depends on the specific value constraints. E.g. if you'd suddenly do a negative credit card charge or whatever when passed negative values… well, you'd want to guard against that as strictly as possible.

Comment: But if wrong values will trigger wrong behaviour and perhaps exceptions in and of themselves in the code, then explicit checking can possibly also be omitted. This is independent of unit tests, which you'll want to do regardless for various scenarios.

Comment: When you say we can omit certain type checks, but that's independet of unit tests, would an example be omitting the integer check above since when creating an array, it'll throw an exception, while keeping the unit test ensuring that the input is an integer?

Comment: Yes, if creating an array from a wrong value throws an exception, there's little need to do a manual test and manually throw an exception before that. That's a good example of a test that can be omitted. You then have the unit test to ensure that this throwing of exceptions for wrong values actually works as expected.

Comment: So with proper type checking (I'm looking into [flow](https://flow.org/)) and inherent exceptions from wrong values we can cut remove basically all the checks above while keeping robustness the same. The unit tests wouldn't need to be touched (assuming flow can throw exceptions). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Yes. Statically typed languages (e.g. C, Java) make this easier, as they won't even execute when you have basic type errors. In dynamically typed languages like Javascript that's not the case so much, and it's what TypeScript et al are retrofitting into the language. You still need to be more aware of what will implicitly throw errors when, and where you do need explicit checks because the language is too dynamic. Finding the right balance is the trick to writing good code.

Comment: Very much agree with the importance of being aware when to put explicit checks vs relying on implicit errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library that helps with this, for example **[is.js](https://github.com/arasatasaygin/is.js)**:

is.number(value:any)

```js
is.number(42);
=> true
```

is.alphanumeric(value:any)

```js
is.all.alphaNumeric('alphaNu3er1k', '*?');
=> false
```

etc..

Comment: This would for sure shorten the length of my lines, but I'm wondering if the lines should be there in the first place

Answer (score -1):

Don't look at whether the code is overwhelmed is a good practice if it leads to safe code running without errors only

edit: sure, and you could use some kind of library, but this way you have access to what you check and how you check it, which makes it easier to modify later if necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).